# Foreach in C# throws null reference exception

Tags: c#, list, exception

I have the following block of code

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Current);
try
{
    foreach (string dir in dirs)
    {
        string[,] dirconf = Read_Dir(dir);
        Element elem = new Element();
        elem.name = dir; // set the current name in a blank element
        if (dirconf[1, 0].Equals("container")) 
            elem.type = ElementType.Container;
        else
            elem.type = ElementType.Project; // set the current type in the element

        // this is where additionalInfo will go

        Branch.Add(elem);
     }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message + "\r\n" + e.Source + "\r\n" + e.InnerException + "\r\n" + e.Data + "\r\n" + e.StackTrace);
}
UpdateUI();
```

That is supposed to get the list of directories, read the configuration of each directory (the Read_Dir function works just fine, tested) and then add the directory to the Branch. Branch is declared as follows

```
List<Element> Branch = new List<Element>();
```

Using the variable watch and debugger, the dirs array gets all the correct stuff, and so does the dirconf one. The element is created OK, and then, at Branch.Add I presume, it gives a "Object reference not set to an instance of object" exception, where it quits the foreach and goes straight to UpdateUI. UpdateUI reads the Branch list, finds it blank, and does nothing.

Comment: You should post the stack trace.

Comment: Why do you "presume"? just debug your code.

Comment: Step through the code line by line, then you will see where exactly the NullReferenceException is thrown. I see `dirconf[1, 0]` as a candidate.

Comment: @Botz3000: My crystal ball was saying the same thing.

Comment: The error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." and it's thrown at the Branch.Add(elem) line. I have the Stack Trace, but I don't how to post it here.

Comment: @andreas.vitikan If you stop debugging at that line and hover over Branch, is it `null`?

Comment: Yes it is. I think I may be declaring it wrong somewhere.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your line:

    List<Element> Branch = new List<Element>();

Does it get hit?

Are you using the `Branch` variable anywhere else?

Comment: @andreas.vitikan ok; you say that when you hover on `Branch` while debugging the loop, `Branch` is `null` ? OK; you've shown *how* `Branch` is declared - but: ***where*** is it declared? And is there any chance some other code is setting it to null?